# Creating a menu in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm currently creating an update of my iOS application and I'm a bit stuck. I've tried to googling around but cannot find a decent answer on this.

I've a menu which links to different views. And I'm not really sure if I've done it the best method.

I've created a view, and added the links into a stack view. Should I considering changing it all to a tableview? or a collection view? Or maybe there's another way?

The current look:

[image: img]

Should I change this to a tableview? collection view? or something else? Or just let it stay as it is?

Comment: Yes, you must use a `UITableView`

Comment: @Augusto TableView is the best way to go? And if so, can I still design it with spacing etc?

Comment: TableView have a property to set a spacing, and if isn't good yet, you can use the constraints inside Cell to make your customized spacing.

Comment: So, in 100% of the cases I should use tableview for such a thing?

Comment: This is really just a design decision. You can use a fixed arrangement of buttons, a table, a collection, a picker, a photo of several dogs each representing some option... whatever gets the job done in a way that appeals to you and (more importantly) your users. Your tab bar is a sort of menu, too. Voting to close this as a matter of opinion because there's just no right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of items in your menu changes at runtime and is large, you should use a table view, because a table view is good for efficiently displaying a screen's worth of items from a large list of items.

If the contents of your menu is small (under maybe two screenfuls of items) and fixed at compile time and you are using a storyboard, then you could use [a table view with static cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW27), if you can make it look the way you want.

If the contents of your menu is small, then you can use a stack view (inside a scroll view) if that is easier for you. There is no particular advantage to using a table view over a stack view to display a small amount of content, unless you need other features of the table view (like the ability to select/deselect rows).

Based on the screen shot you posted, I'd either use a table view with static cells (since the screen shot is from a storyboard) or a stack view, depending on whether I can get the appearance I want from a table view. If, as in the screen shot, the buttons must be centered vertically, I'd use a stack view, because it's easier to vertically center the content with a stack view.

Answer (score 0):

Look, the fact of have many itens on your screen is clear on the mobile applications, to make it easy, we have collecions view like `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`. On the `UITableView`'s case, this implements the scrolling and have methods do handle the operations' list, you can see the documentation to check these methods: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview.

**Main reasons to use `UITableView`**

- Implements scroll behavior.
- Independent of size screen you can access all itens.
- Easy to detect interactions like tap on cell.
- Easy to make changes, like insert and remove content.

The `UITableView` exists precisely to solve problems like you has.

Comment: And this menu can easily be done with a stack view of buttons. A table view is not necessarily the best option.

Comment: As far I know, `UIStackView` not have scroll behavior implemented, to do this, I must add a `UIScrollView` on screen, it's sounds not needed when use a `UITableView`, besides that the callback's tap it's more hard to implement than `didSelectRow`'s `UITableView`

Comment: It's not needed because `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. However, it is more difficult to vertically center the content with a table view than with a stack view, so if the vertical centering shown in the screen shot is a requirement, it's probably easier to use a stack view.

Comment: @robmayoff make a nice explanation, but in my view, I keeping prefer use a `UITableView`.